# Перенаправление трафика

Tags: ubuntu

Есть приложение которое общается с внешним сокетом, нужно весь трафик перенаправить на localhost. Пробовал через /etc/hosts, он перенаправляет только если подключение идет к порту 80 или 443. мне же нужно трафик 5005 порта.

К примеру если бы ip источник был в сетевом шлюзе то я бы мог сделать так

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --dst [source_ip] -p tcp --dport 5005 -j DNAT --to-destination [destination_ip]
```

Но проблема в том, что [source_ip] внешний.

Comment: /etc/hosts не имеет никакого отношения к портам. Так что в итоге непонятно о чём вообще речь

Comment: @andreymal обновил вопрос, надеюсь более внятно объяснил свою проблему

Answer (score 0):

Может кому понадобится, нашел вариант через iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d [source_ip] --dport 5005 -j DNAT --to-destination [dest_ip]
```